# I want to read this csv file with pandas and display the first 5 records but I keep getting this error

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting an error when i use df.head() on my dataframe I read in.

When I read in my CSV file and attempt to display The first 5 records, I use these lines

```
df=pd.read_csv('US_Accidents_Dec21.csv')
df.head()
```

But I Get the following error and I want to know how to fix it.

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:707, in PlainTextFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    700 stream = StringIO()
    701 printer = pretty.RepresentationPrinter(stream, self.verbose,
    702     self.max_width, self.newline,
    703     max_seq_length=self.max_seq_length,
    704     singleton_pprinters=self.singleton_printers,
    705     type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    706     deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 707 printer.pretty(obj)
    708 printer.flush()
    709 return stream.getvalue()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py:410, in RepresentationPrinter.pretty(self, obj)
    407                         return meth(obj, self, cycle)
    408                 if cls is not object \
    409                         and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 410                     return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    412     return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    413 finally:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py:778, in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    776 """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    777 # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 778 output = repr(obj)
    779 lines = output.splitlines()
    780 with p.group():

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1011, in DataFrame.__repr__(self)
   1008     return buf.getvalue()
   1010 repr_params = fmt.get_dataframe_repr_params()
-> 1011 return self.to_string(**repr_params)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1192, in DataFrame.to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, line_width, min_rows, max_colwidth, encoding)
   1173 with option_context("display.max_colwidth", max_colwidth):
   1174     formatter = fmt.DataFrameFormatter(
   1175         self,
   1176         columns=columns,
   (...)
   1190         decimal=decimal,
   1191     )
-> 1192     return fmt.DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_string(
   1193         buf=buf,
   1194         encoding=encoding,
   1195         line_width=line_width,
   1196     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1128, in DataFrameRenderer.to_string(self, buf, encoding, line_width)
   1125 from pandas.io.formats.string import StringFormatter
   1127 string_formatter = StringFormatter(self.fmt, line_width=line_width)
-> 1128 string = string_formatter.to_string()
   1129 return save_to_buffer(string, buf=buf, encoding=encoding)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py:25, in StringFormatter.to_string(self)
     24 def to_string(self) -> str:
---> 25     text = self._get_string_representation()
     26     if self.fmt.should_show_dimensions:
     27         text = "".join([text, self.fmt.dimensions_info])

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py:40, in StringFormatter._get_string_representation(self)
     37 if self.fmt.frame.empty:
     38     return self._empty_info_line
---> 40 strcols = self._get_strcols()
     42 if self.line_width is None:
     43     # no need to wrap around just print the whole frame
     44     return self.adj.adjoin(1, *strcols)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\string.py:31, in StringFormatter._get_strcols(self)
     30 def _get_strcols(self) -> list[list[str]]:
---> 31     strcols = self.fmt.get_strcols()
     32     if self.fmt.is_truncated:
     33         strcols = self._insert_dot_separators(strcols)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:611, in DataFrameFormatter.get_strcols(self)
    607 def get_strcols(self) -> list[list[str]]:
    608     """
    609     Render a DataFrame to a list of columns (as lists of strings).
    610     """
--> 611     strcols = self._get_strcols_without_index()
    613     if self.index:
    614         str_index = self._get_formatted_index(self.tr_frame)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:875, in DataFrameFormatter._get_strcols_without_index(self)
    871 cheader = str_columns[i]
    872 header_colwidth = max(
    873     int(self.col_space.get(c, 0)), *(self.adj.len(x) for x in cheader)
    874 )
--> 875 fmt_values = self.format_col(i)
    876 fmt_values = _make_fixed_width(
    877     fmt_values, self.justify, minimum=header_colwidth, adj=self.adj
    878 )
    880 max_len = max(max(self.adj.len(x) for x in fmt_values), header_colwidth)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:889, in DataFrameFormatter.format_col(self, i)
    887 frame = self.tr_frame
    888 formatter = self._get_formatter(i)
--> 889 return format_array(
    890     frame.iloc[:, i]._values,
    891     formatter,
    892     float_format=self.float_format,
    893     na_rep=self.na_rep,
    894     space=self.col_space.get(frame.columns[i]),
    895     decimal=self.decimal,
    896     leading_space=self.index,
    897 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1316, in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal, leading_space, quoting)
   1301     digits = get_option("display.precision")
   1303 fmt_obj = fmt_klass(
   1304     values,
   1305     digits=digits,
   (...)
   1313     quoting=quoting,
   1314 )
-> 1316 return fmt_obj.get_result()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1347, in GenericArrayFormatter.get_result(self)
   1346 def get_result(self) -> list[str]:
-> 1347     fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1348     return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1594, in FloatArrayFormatter._format_strings(self)
   1593 def _format_strings(self) -> list[str]:
-> 1594     return list(self.get_result_as_array())

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1511, in FloatArrayFormatter.get_result_as_array(self)
   1508     return formatted
   1510 if self.formatter is not None:
-> 1511     return format_with_na_rep(self.values, self.formatter, self.na_rep)
   1513 if self.fixed_width:
   1514     threshold = get_option("display.chop_threshold")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1503, in FloatArrayFormatter.get_result_as_array.<locals>.format_with_na_rep(values, formatter, na_rep)
   1500 def format_with_na_rep(values: ArrayLike, formatter: Callable, na_rep: str):
   1501     mask = isna(values)
   1502     formatted = np.array(
-> 1503         [
   1504             formatter(val) if not m else na_rep
   1505             for val, m in zip(values.ravel(), mask.ravel())
   1506         ]
   1507     ).reshape(values.shape)
   1508     return formatted

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1504, in <listcomp>(.0)
   1500 def format_with_na_rep(values: ArrayLike, formatter: Callable, na_rep: str):
   1501     mask = isna(values)
   1502     formatted = np.array(
   1503         [
-> 1504             formatter(val) if not m else na_rep
   1505             for val, m in zip(values.ravel(), mask.ravel())
   1506         ]
   1507     ).reshape(values.shape)
   1508     return formatted

KeyError: ';,'
```

Its a lot to paste here and I dont know exactly what to detail because Im a beginner with using Python.

Comment: We don't know what the error is. please provide the full error message (traceback).

Comment: @Clegane I edited my post, sorry about that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives the following exception: `KeyError: ';,'`.

I suggest verifying that your CSV-file doesn't contain any errors first. Are you able to open it in e.g. Excel? If yes: are you using the correct separator and delimiter? (See the `sep` and `delimiter` parameters in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))